# Calling a function with dollar sign in front

Tags: php

I'm new to php, and I found a tutorial about cropping image, with a strange instruction I never see. I don't know how to search about it.

```
$src_img = $image_create($source_file);
```

Here it is the full code of the tutorial

```
 //resize and crop image by center
function resize_crop_image($max_width, $max_height, $source_file, $dst_dir, $quality = 80){
    $imgsize = getimagesize($source_file);
    $width = $imgsize[0];
    $height = $imgsize[1];
    $mime = $imgsize['mime'];

    switch($mime){
        case 'image/gif':
            $image_create = "imagecreatefromgif";
            $image = "imagegif";
            break;

        case 'image/png':
            $image_create = "imagecreatefrompng";
            $image = "imagepng";
            $quality = 7;
            break;

        case 'image/jpeg':
            $image_create = "imagecreatefromjpeg";
            $image = "imagejpeg";
            $quality = 80;
            break;

        default:
            return false;
            break;
    }

    $dst_img = imagecreatetruecolor($max_width, $max_height);
    $src_img = $image_create($source_file);

    $width_new = $height * $max_width / $max_height;
    $height_new = $width * $max_height / $max_width;
    //if the new width is greater than the actual width of the image, then the height is too large and the rest cut off, or vice versa
    if($width_new > $width){
        //cut point by height
        $h_point = (($height - $height_new) / 2);
        //copy image
        imagecopyresampled($dst_img, $src_img, 0, 0, 0, $h_point, $max_width, $max_height, $width, $height_new);
    }else{
        //cut point by width
        $w_point = (($width - $width_new) / 2);
        imagecopyresampled($dst_img, $src_img, 0, 0, $w_point, 0, $max_width, $max_height, $width_new, $height);
    }

    $image($dst_img, $dst_dir, $quality);

    if($dst_img)imagedestroy($dst_img);
    if($src_img)imagedestroy($src_img);
}
//usage example
resize_crop_image(100, 100, "test.jpg", "test.jpg");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$image_create` returns a string.

This sting is a dynamic function (whose name is decided run time)

Reference:

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php

Instead of adding 3 if statements for choosing three functions:
 `imagecreatefromgif()`, `imagecreatefrompng()` and `imagecreatefromjpeg()`,
 a variable is taken which will switch the function variable (name) and that will be used.

Which is easier to use.

Answer (score 5):

First up: I don't know what tutorial you're following, but it doesn't look to be a particularly good one. The code, to my eye, looks very messy and a bit dated. It also doesn't follow [the coding standards](http://php-fig.org) at all... I'd steer clear.

To answer your question, though:

```
$image_create = 'imagecreatefromjpeg';
```

Is assigning a string to the variable, at first glance, but that string happens to be [a function name](http://php.net/imagecreatefromjpeg), too. Basically, read this:

```
$src_img = $image_create($source_file);
```

as either one of three calls:

```
$src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_file);
//or
$src_img = imagecreatefrompng($source_file);
//or
$src_img = imagecreatefromgif($source_file);
```

Depending on the value of `$image_create`...

Comment: Personally, I'd save the "first up" for a footnote and just answer the question first.

Answer (score 2):

It is calling a function via a variable that contains the function's name.

Note that `$image_create` is set depending on what type of image the code is trying to create. This allows the rest of the code that doesn't care about the image type to be consolidated, which is a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

In other words...

```
src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_file);
```

is-the-same-as...

```
$image_create = 'imagecreatefromjpeg';
src_img = $image_create($source_file);
```